# php equivalent for mcrypt_decrypt in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mcrypt, cryptojs

I am using following code in php

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secretKey, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $vector);
```

In javascript it does not return similar output as php
I have used the code:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey);
var iv=    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(vector);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptText,key,{iv:iv,padding:CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
```

Comment: Are the formats of the incoming key/vector the same (ie not encoded or padded differently)? fwiw `mcrypt_decrypt` is very depricated. Hopefully legacy example.

Comment: Try using zero padding in your javascript code. mcrypt uses zero padding by default, not PKCS7.

Comment: tried with zero padding also but not worked